# Map property names as string to an object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a list like so:

```
props[0].Alias = "Name";
props[0].Value = "Alex";

props[1].Alias = "Amount";
props[1].Value = "10";

props[2].Alias = "AdressCity";
props[2].Value = "Montreal";
```

which I need to map to a object like this (and backwards also):

```
myObject.Name ("Alex")
myObject.Amount (10)
myObject.Adress.City ("Montreal")
```

Is this possible with AutoMapper? If not how could this be done?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/walkthrough-creating-and-using-dynamic-objects

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<string, int>().ConvertUsing(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
});
var source = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"Age", "100"}, {"Name", "Kate"}};
var myObject= configuration.CreateMapper().Map<MyObject>(source);
```